# net/core modules (CONFIG_NET)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Anyone knows if we can remove CONFIG_NET=y in linux kernel config for android phone?

I found a crash that might have caused by net components and trying to debug if disabling this will make it more stable. Thanks

Comment: I never tried it myself, but my feeling is that disabling "CONFIG_NET" will leave you with a barely functional linux system, incompatible with a great deal of apps. If you were configuring a "closed" embedded system, you could test your application thoroughly; if user apps are to be run on the system, then don't disable the CONFIG_NET outright; rather try to isolate the exact point of failure.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from manually editing the **.config** file and "removing" a configuration entry.  But just because you "can" does not mean it's advisable.  In fact proper practice is to not manually edit the **.config** file, as that may break dependencies and cause a build failure.  Instead you should use `make menuconfig`.  Very likely you will not be able to disable **"CONFIG_NET** at all (without first disabling all the features that depend on that configuration entry).